# how to load own Map service in ios and android

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode8

i have a requirement to load a own map service in xcode8 ios and android studio. without using any existing services, eg - OSM, MAPKIT, MAPBOX, GOOGLE MAPS,...

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, you can use MapKit, and add a MKTileOverlay to it to show your own map tiles.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay

Here's a link to a tutorial: http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/

Keep in mind that the tutorial is written for Swift 2, and the syntax is a bit different on Swift 3.

Comment: i need to use my own map service without using any existing services. just need to show our map in a view in xcode

Comment: Which format are your own maps in? With MKTileOverlay you can show your own maps without any existing services..

Comment: i'm using own OSM tile rendering service and i want to integrate with an ios app

Comment: If your OSM tiles are in format of Z/X/Y.png, you can use them easily with MKTileOverlay. I can provide you sample code if you want.